# Apache POI. Calculate the height of the generated (through template) DOCX document page

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to generate one-page `.docx` document through `pl.jsolve.templ4docx.core.Docx` and `Apache POI`. I load template and fill it with list of variables (variable length), so the height of the page must increase. I don't want to appear the second page.
I have tried to calculate it via `countLines * lineHeight`, but this

```
XWPFDocument doc = loadTemplateAndFillVariables();
int countLines = doc.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getLines()
```

gives me zero :( and here explaned why: http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Getting-the-line-count-of-docx-file-created-using-POI-3-10-td5719024.html (you may not know how many lines there are in the document until it has been rendered)

I trying to use `doc.getBodyElements()` (my template contains only XWPFParagraph and XWPFTable), but also can't find method to calculate height/countLines.

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, this is no problem, when appear second page in generated document, because when you print this document, empty pages are ignored...